# Comprobar si los inputs están vacios con jquery

Tags: jquery, html

He estado mirando un montón de preguntas para este mismo tema y no he encontrado nada así que me veo obligado a formular una nueva...

Tengo un formulario tal que así :

```js
var value=$.trim($(".form-control").val());
if(value.length>0)
{
    $("#user-data-next-button").attr('disabled', true);
} else{
    $("#user-data-next-button").attr('disabled', false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="userdevdata.php" method="post">
 <label>Email</label>
 <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email"/>
 <label>Full name</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"/>
 <label>Address</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address"/>
 <label>Postal code</label>
 <input type="number" class="form-control" name="cp"/>
 <label>City</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city"/>
 <label>Province</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="province"/>
</form>
<button id="user-data-next-button" class="btn my-button" disabled="true" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
```

Lo que yo necesito es que, mientras todos los campos de mi formulario no estén completos, el botón esté desactivado (disabled). En cambio, cuando yo complete todos los campos del formulario, el botón se debe activar (`disabled="false"`) para que sea pulsable.

---

```
     var userdevdata = 6;
 if($("#usermail").val().length > 0){ userdevdata = userdevdata-1;}
 if($("#username").val().length > 0){ userdevdata = userdevdata-1;}
 if($("#useraddress").val().length > 0){ userdevdata = userdevdata-1;}
 if($("#usercp").val().length > 0){ userdevdata = userdevdata-1;}
 if($("#usercity").val().length > 0){ userdevdata = userdevdata-1;}
 if($("#userprovince").val().length > 0){ userdevdata = userdevdata-1;}
 if(userdevdata == 0){
     $('#user-data-next-button').attr('disabled', false);
 } else {
     $('#user-data-next-button').attr('disabled', true);
 }
```

No me manejo muy bien con esto de los comentarios. He hecho esto y no me funciona no sé si está bien o mal.

GRacias.

Comment: echale un ojo a [Jquery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) igual puede servir para tu proposito

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para ello, necesitas saber la longitud de caracteres que hay en cada uno de los inputs de tu formulario.

Basándome en tu **HTML**, te incluyo un pequeño script en **jQuery** que te permitirá eso:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Siempre que salgamos de un campo de texto, se chequeará esta función
    $("#form input").keyup(function() {
        var form = $(this).parents("#form");
        var check = checkCampos(form);
        if(check) {
            $("#user-data-next-button").prop("disabled", false);
        }
        else {
            $("#user-data-next-button").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});

//Función para comprobar los campos de texto
function checkCampos(obj) {
    var camposRellenados = true;
    obj.find("input").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
        if( $this.val().length <= 0 ) {
            camposRellenados = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if(camposRellenados == false) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Deberás añadir un ID al formulario, o una clase y lo cambias en el código.

A groso modo, este código lo que hace es buscar todos los campos inputs y chequea si su longitud es mayor a 0 (ha escrito algo), y si todos los campos están rellenados, entonces, le quita la propiedad disabled al botón.

Añado un enlace al [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3cLjstko/2/) por si necesitas trastear con él.

Comment: Gracias, funciona bien, pero el problema es que el botón no se activa cuando clico en el, si no cuando le doy a tabulación, es decir para un usuario normal (gente que no sabe que existe la tecla tabulación) les será imposible pulsar el botón...

Comment: Vale no solo funciona con tabulación pero antes de poder darle al botón tengo que clickar fuera del formulario y luego el botón, como puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, en vez de un `blur()` utiliza un `keyup()` y el botón será clickable mientras escribe si están los campos rellenos

Comment: Gracias, yo he probado y también me funciona con .hover()

Comment: De nada, estamos para ayudarnos!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una variable numérica igual al numero de campos que tienes, cada vez que un campo no este vacío.

```
if($("#nombre").val().length > 0)
```

restas uno a la variable numérica y compruebas si es igual a cero. si es igual a cero quitas el disabled.

Comment: No sé si está bien, ya que en jquery soy algo nuevo y no me lo manejo demasiado bien, pero lo que he hecho no me funciona

Comment: var userdevdata = 6;
  if($("#usermail").val().length > 0){ userdevdata = userdevdata-1;}
  if($("#username").val().length > 0){ userdevdata = userdevdata-1;}
  if($("#useraddress").val().length > 0){ userdevdata = userdevdata-1;}
  if($("#usercp").val().length > 0){ userdevdata = userdevdata-1;}
  if($("#usercity").val().length > 0){ userdevdata = userdevdata-1;}
  if($("#userprovince").val().length > 0){ userdevdata = userdevdata-1;}
  if(userdevdata == 0){
   $('#user-data-next-button').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
   $('#user-data-next-button').attr('disabled', true);

Comment: tendrias que usar la propiedad change de jquery https://api.jquery.com/change/ para saber en que momento ha cambiado

Answer (score 0):

Lo más directo es preguntar por cada uno de los campos para saber si se han rellenado y si alguno está vacío almacenarlo en una variable y en función de su valor mostrar o no el botón.
...

El el formulario añade ids

```
input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"/>
```

...
con jquery para campo del formulario

```
var contador=0
    if ($("#email").val().length<1) {contador=1}
```

or

```
if ($("#email").val()=="") {contador=1}

if (contador==0) {//muestras el botón}
else {//no muestras el botón}
```

Si preguntas por la clase que es común a todos los campos tomará el valor de un solo campo, no de todos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el evento [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) para hacer las comprobaciones:

```js
$('input').on('input', function(){
  
    $('input').each(function() {
      
      var boton      = $( '#user-data-next-button' );
      var esta_vacio = $( this ).prop( 'value' ) === '';
      
      boton.prop('disabled', esta_vacio);        
    });
});

$('button').on('click', function(){  
  console.log('Enviado!!');
});
```

```css
input{display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>Email</label>
 <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email"/>
 <label>Full name</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"/>
 <label>Address</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address"/>
 <label>Postal code</label>
 <input type="number" class="form-control" name="cp"/>
 <label>City</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city"/>
 <label>Province</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="province"/>
</form>  
<button id="user-data-next-button" class="btn my-button" disabled>Enviar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $inputs = $('#SignupForm').find('table').children().find(':input[type="text"]') //INPUTS
var $selects = $('#SignupForm').find('table').children().find('select') //SELECTS

$inputs.each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(element).val().length <= 0) {
            $(element).css("border", "solid 2px #FA5858");
    }
});

$selects.each(function(index, element) {
    if ( $(element).val() ==0) {
            $(element).css("border", "solid 2px #FA5858");
    }
});
```

Comment: Aun que buen código habla para si mismo, tu respuesta sería más fácil de entender para un publico de amplio espectro en sus conocimientos si explicas con un par de palabras donde exactamente era el problema y como lo solucionas.